# How to select from a list of results for one column taking a second column as a reference?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sku_attributes table with this data

```
attribute_id    sku_id
1                   1
3                   1
10                  1
1                   2
4                   2
10                  2
1                   3
5                   3
```

Let's say I have a result set with three values

```
1, 3, 10
```

I want to query all the data that exactly match with the result set on the attribute_id column.
The sku_id column must have the same value on each result.
The expected result should be like this:

```
attribute_id    sku_id
1                   1
3                   1
10                  1
```

I tried with IN statement but returns all that matches with any data from the result set

```
select * from sku_attributes sa
where sa.attribute_id in
    (1, 3, 10)
```

Comment: Why do you call '1,3,10' a 'result set'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `sku_id`and take only those groups having no other `attribute_id`s than you specify  and all of the ones you want

```
select sku_id 
from sku_attributes
group by sku_id
having sum(attribute_id not in (1, 3, 10)) = 0
and sum(attribute_id = 1) > 0
and sum(attribute_id = 3) > 0
and sum(attribute_id = 10) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like, a concise method for this is:

```
select sku_id 
from sku_attributes
group by sku_id
having group_concat(attribute_id order by attribute_id) = '1,3,10');
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is more useful to have only one result instead the whole list.